# Сalculating the square of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

There was a difficulty with the calculation of this matrix, I would be very grateful if someone would help with it:

$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
    1 & \epsilon & \epsilon^2 & \ldots & \epsilon^{n-1}\\
    1 & \epsilon^2 & \epsilon^4 & \ldots & \epsilon^{2(n-1)}\\
    \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
    1 & \epsilon^{n-1} & \epsilon^{2(n-1)} & \ldots & \epsilon^{(n-1)^2}\\
\end{pmatrix}^2  при\; \epsilon = e^{2\pi i/n}$

Comment: Looks like a DFT matrix to me. Shouldn't $\epsilon = e^{-i2\pi/n}$?

Comment: @Ricky You're right, I forgot i to the degree of epsilon, but there is no minus there, I corrected the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbering the rows and columns from $0$ to $n-1$ the $(i, j)$th element of the squared matrix is $1 + \epsilon^{i + j} + \epsilon^{2(i + j)} + \ldots + \epsilon^{(n-1)(i+j)}$
which equals $n$ when $i+j \equiv 0 \mod n  $ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Very nice. These are roots of unity - the ones that are vertices of a regular n-gon, right?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee yes, they are that.